# CouchDB Fauxton - How to navigate through revisions history?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, revision-history

I've been using CouchDB for some time now, and I am currently testing CouchDB 2 and Fauxton on local env. One thing really disturbing compared to the good old Futon is that it is not possible with Fauxton to navigate through document revisions history.

Is it really not implemented with this new React tool or did I miss it ?
Is there a Fauxton add-on that implements this missing feature ?

[image: In Futon]
[image: In Fauxton]

Comment: I'm currently asking myself the same question and It seems not implemented. I went through the JIRA issue and no one mentioned it. You might want to create an issue.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2163

Comment: Yes, great, I did see that thread on Jira. Really active thread indeed ;)
 Priority: Major / Created: 24 Feb 2014 / Last update: 27 Oct 2015 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Fauxton only shows the "latest" document's revision and there is no option to navigate through document revisions history.

As per CouchDB team - https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/issues/1069

> Prior "revisions" exist only as a means to an end - consistent
>   replication. Compaction (and the automatic compaction daemon) or
>   replication can remove them at any time.

You can get additional information about the revisions for a given document by supplying the _revs_info argument to the query:

```
curl -X GET http://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>/<DOC_ID>?revs_info=true
```

> "_revs_info":[
>         {
>            "rev":"3-427991477c64de15dec603992bf4904a",
>            "status":"available"
>         },
>         {
>            "rev":"2-4cf070a1cb53ea5bf9554d665c8ba3e8",
>            "status":"available"
>         },
>         {
>            "rev":"1-2cee5b1e853387851535d34d0f056fb2",
>            "status":"missing"
>         }    ]

Now you can access the previous version of the document revisions via CouchDB HTTP API:

```
curl -X GET http://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>/<DOC_ID>?rev=2-4cf070a1cb53ea5bf9554d665c8ba3e8
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that The Apache team decided that it will be a "Won't fix" for that feature. They explain that on an [issue on Fauxton Github](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/issues/1069)

The point is that we should not rely on revisions since compaction might delete it.
The last solution is to develop a plugin for it.